# How to regulate output traffic with iptables

Tags: linux, debian, iptables, ddos

I'm hosting several websites, and some of them use scripts to ddos externals servers from my server. 
There is a possibility to control the outgoing traffic by, for example, limiting the number of request per second or so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some example to prevent DOS, you can man iptables to search the keyword '**limit, connlimit, hitcount**' for more informations.

Allow 5 new connection packets per second

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --syn -m limit --limit 1/s --limit-burst 5 -j ACCEPT
```

Allow 30 connections during 60 seconds each IP.

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m recent --name BAD_HTTP_ACCESS --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 30 -j REJECT
```

50 max connections per IP to httpd

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 50 -j REJECT
```

Comment: So this will stop say, an application on my server, spamming other servers with bad packets?

Comment: No, it's a limitation for output traffic, prevent too much response to other clients. If you want to block bad packets, you have to define rules in 'INPUT'  table instead of 'OUTPUT' .